# RSpec: Controller not updating record in test env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is kind of a weird question so I'll probably be editing this to fill in some context as needed. I have an RSpec test:

```
    it "should update object paramaters" do
      put :update, params: {id: test_project, project: valid_params}
      test_project.reload
      expect(test_project.title).to eql valid_params[:title]
      expect(test_project.created_at).to_not eql test_project.updated_at
    end
```

Relevant controller action:

```
  # @project is defined in a before_action
  def update
    if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
      redirect_to @project, flash: { success: "Project successfully updated!" }
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

This request returns a 200 OK (I would expect a redirect code, but this is not the case) response code, however when I reload `test_project` the title remains unchanged and the test fails. This EXACT same request works to update the Project in the development and production environments. Any clues as to why this isn't working?

Comment: I don't actually see a `reload` in the test (you should do one there).  The 200 would suggest eihter (a) there's a user authenticaiton step that you've not handled in your tests or (b) there's a validation issue. You can test for either / both by using `gem 'pry'` and `binding.pry` in your upate method. If the pry doesn't execute in update, then update isn't executing (perhaps user authentication issue) and if it does execute, you can look at `@project.errors.full_messages` to see what the issue is.

Comment: Your suggestion for prying to find error messages helped me solve this problem. Go ahead and post it as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: Glad to, answer now posted. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually see a reload in the test (you should do one there). The 200 would suggest either (a) there's a user authentication step that you've not handled in your tests or (b) there's a validation issue. You can test for either / both by using `gem 'pry'` and `binding.pry` in your update method. If the pry doesn't execute in update, then update isn't executing (perhaps user authentication issue) and if it does execute, you can look at @project.errors.full_messages to see what the issue is.